# Django generating a subquery in the group-by clause of SQL query

Tags: sql, django, orm

I have models like this:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class EmployeeProject(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='employee_projects',
    )
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.ForeignKey(ProjectRole, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    skill_level = models.ForeignKey(SkillLevel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hourly_rate = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=9)

class TaskRole(LogOnSaveMixin, DiffModel):
    task = models.ForeignKey(
       Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
       related_name='roles',
    )
    estimated_hours = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

And I have a queryset like this:

```
qs = Task.objects.all()


user = self.request.user
host_roles = EmployeeProject.objects.filter(
      employee=user.employee,
)
qs = qs.annotate(
    total_estimated_hours=Sum('roles__estimated_hours'),
)
open_tasks_qs = qs.filter(
   Q(project__in=host_roles.values('project_id')),
 ).filter(
            (
                Q(total_estimated_hours__isnull=False)
            ),
        )

qs = open_tasks_qs | qs.filter(author=user).distinct()
qs = qs.values('id')
qs = qs.distinct()
return qs
```

The problem is that this query yields an error, saying that

```
more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

The corresponding sql looks like this:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT "tasks_task"."id" 
FROM 
  "tasks_task" 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "tasks_taskrole" ON (
    "tasks_task"."id" = "tasks_taskrole"."task_id"
  ) 
GROUP BY 
  "tasks_task"."id", 
  (
    SELECT 
      U0."project_id" 
    FROM 
      "tasks_employeeproject" U0 
    WHERE 
      U0."employee_id" = 1
  ) 
HAVING 
  (
    (
      "tasks_task"."project_id" IN (
        SELECT 
          U0."project_id" 
        FROM 
          "tasks_employeeproject" U0 
        WHERE 
          U0."employee_id" = 1
      ) 
      AND SUM(
        "tasks_taskrole"."estimated_hours"
      ) IS NOT NULL
    ) 
    OR "tasks_task"."author_id" = 1
  ) 
ORDER BY 
  "tasks_task"."id" DESC
```

There are two questions:

1. How to fix the issue?
2. I thought that I am quite experienced in SQL, but how can a subquery be part of a group-by clause? I tried to google the documentation of SQL, but didn't find anything. This surprised me a lot.

Comment: 2) No, not in standard SQL. (Perhaps some product allows it.)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try like this

```
Task.objects.annotate(
        total_estimated_hours=Sum('roles__estimated_hours')
    ).filter(
        projects__employee_projects__employee = request.user.employee,
        total_estimated_hours__isnull=False
    )
```

Here I am looking up the employee through the reverse relation from `EmployeeProject` to `Projects`. More information can be found in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).